# cant find relative path of the file in java web application?

Tags: java, path

> cant find relative path of the file in java

```
String excelFilePath = "E:/javawork/quicksense/WebContent/pages/new.xlsx";
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
```

Comment: it works well on local host but when i upload on live actual server the file is not found.

Comment: You have to check the path where the file is on the actual server...

Comment: i dont not the path?
can you tell me the method to find the path?